# How to get Outlook smtp certificate?

Tags: certificate, ssl-certificate, client-certificates

I am trying to get smtp certificate from outlook, so I can import it into my weblogic server but I have problems with getting the certificate.

For the imap certificate I didn´t have any problem with getting the certificate.

In my linux terminal I use the next command.

```
openssl s_client -connect outlook.office365.com:993
openssl s_client -connect smtp.office365.com:587
```

[image]

The outlook port and server list
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ESMTP uses a delayed-start TLS session (via the STARTTLS verb).

You need to add `-starttls smtp` to your command.

```
$ openssl s_client -connect smtp.office365.com:587 -starttls smtp
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = DigiCert Global Root CA
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, CN = DigiCert Cloud Services CA-1
verify return:1
depth=0 C = US, ST = WASHINGTON, L = Redmond, O = Microsoft Corporation, CN = outlook.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=WASHINGTON/L=Redmond/O=Microsoft Corporation/CN=outlook.com
   i:/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/CN=DigiCert Cloud Services CA-1
 1 s:/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/CN=DigiCert Cloud Services CA-1
   i:/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert Global Root CA
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/C=US/ST=WASHINGTON/L=Redmond/O=Microsoft Corporation/CN=outlook.com
issuer=/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/CN=DigiCert Cloud Services CA-1
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Client Certificate Types: RSA sign, DSA sign, ECDSA sign
Requested Signature Algorithms: RSA+SHA512:ECDSA+SHA512:RSA+SHA256:RSA+SHA384:RSA+SHA1:ECDSA+SHA256:ECDSA+SHA384:ECDSA+SHA1:DSA+SHA1
Shared Requested Signature Algorithms: RSA+SHA512:ECDSA+SHA512:RSA+SHA256:RSA+SHA384:RSA+SHA1:ECDSA+SHA256:ECDSA+SHA384:ECDSA+SHA1:DSA+SHA1
Peer signing digest: SHA1
Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-384, 384 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 3765 bytes and written 566 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384
    ...
---
250 SMTPUTF8
DONE
```